# if button disabled change text (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Working with forms. Currently the button is disabled until an option is chosen in my `<select>` here is an example:

HTML:

```
<select id="choose-size" class="form-control input-sm">
 <option selected disabled>Select Sizes</option>
 <option>Small</option>
 <option>Medium</option>
 <option>Large</option>
 <option>X Large</option>
</select>

<button id="cart-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg cart-btn" disabled>
ADD TO CART
</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#choose-size').one('change', function() {
     $('#cart-btn').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

How would I change the text `ADD TO CART` to `SELECT SIZE` when the button is in disabled state. When the size is selected then the text change to `ADD TO CART`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
// binds an event handler to the 'change' event of the '#choose-size' element:
$('#choose-size').change(function(){
    // finds the ':selected' option:
    var opt = $(this).find('option:selected');
    // selects the '#cart-btn' element:
    $('#cart-btn')
    // sets the 'disabled' property of the element to true
    // (if the option is disabled) or false (if the option is *not* disabled):
    .prop('disabled', opt.prop('disabled'))
    // sets the text of the button according to the option being disabled or not:
    .text(function(){
        return opt.prop('disabled') ? 'Select size' : 'Add to cart';
    });
// triggers the 'change' event, to run the event-handler on page-load:
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/35UMb/2/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 1):

use:
$('#cart-btn').text("ADD TO CART");

Answer (score 1):

you can use your html and modify your JS code to:

```
$('#choose-size').one('change', function() {
 $('#cart-btn').prop('disabled', false).text('ADD TO CART');});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L9sTQ/. Here you have the entire code.

Comment: small. I like this too!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/UD5rY/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($('#cart-btn').prop('disabled')){     //if disabled
        $('#cart-btn').html('SELECT SIZE');  //or .text()
    }

    $('#choose-size').one('change', function() {
     $('#cart-btn').prop('disabled', false).html('ADD TO CART');     //or .text()
    });

});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($("#choose-size option:selected" ).text() == 'Select Sizes'){
    //if the selected option is default option
        $('#cart-btn').html('SELECT SIZE');
    }

    $('#choose-size').one('change', function() {
     $('#cart-btn').prop('disabled', false).html('ADD TO CART');     //or .text()
    });

});
```